# Join table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql

Hi i would like to ask i get an error when i run this code , can i know how to fix it,  i want to know the doctor for this patient when i enter the patient id, thank you. below is my code

```
DECLARE
  patientid(3)  := &pt_id;
  dname     doc_name%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT doc_name
    INTO dname
    FROM doctor
    JOIN patient
      ON doctor.doc_id = patient.doc_id
   WHERE pt_id = patientid;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('He/She is the patient of Dr.' || dname);
END;
```

Comment: *I get the error* what is the error? Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also when you follow *minimal* part of the described term you'll easily get all the information you need to resolve the issue

Comment: ORA-06550: line 3, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   constant exception <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long
   double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national
   character nchar
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Comment: ORA-06550: line 9, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PATIENT" when expecting one of the following:

   , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Please, post the errors in your original question via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67660623/edit). And did you carefully read the line 3? The error is really in it.

Answer (score 2):

What is `patient(3)` supposed to be? Datatype is missing!

Though, consider something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    -- No         : patientid(3):=&pt_id;
  3    -- Better     : patientid varchar2(3) := &pt_id;  -- is it VARCHAR2? or NUMBER? Who knows ...
  4    -- Even better:
  5    l_pt_id   patient.pt_id%type := &par_pt_id;
  6    l_dname   doctor.doc_name%type;
  7  begin
  8    select d.doc_name
  9      into l_dname
 10      from doctor d join patient p on d.doc_id = p.doc_id
 11     where p.pt_id = l_pt_id;
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line ('He/She is the patient of Dr. '|| l_dname);
 14  end;
 15  /
Enter value for par_pt_id: 100
He/She is the patient of Dr. Luffy

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: i get it know , thanks for the help mate , so my datatype is missing right. thank you so much mate